# Нативный код Mono

Tags: c#, mono

Как известно, Mono компилирует код С# в нативный код (машинный байт-код, как говорит Википедия).  Как код не-промежуточного языка может восприниматься правильно на разных машинах с разными операционными системами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы про AOT компилятор в Mono, то он компилирует под конкретную машину с конкретной ОС.

Comment: При использовании AOT переносимости нет?

Comment: @BjornMelgaard: Нету, а как может быть в принципе? Вы скомпилировали в машинный код конкретной машины.

Нужна переносимость — пользуйтесь JIT. Или компилируйте AOT-компилятором на машине пользователя.

Comment: Очень интересно
=)

Comment: Переносимость будет если вы будете использовать среду исполнения .Net-Mono с Jit компилятором. К примеру, exe файл можно запустить на различных OS Linux командой mono <имя программы>.exe. Причем я пробовал собирать в релиз AnyCPU и запускать на ARM процессоре. Есть конечно тонкости, но в целом это работает. К примеру WinForms запускается или приложение на базе GTK.